# State does not change in my reducer when action is dispatched

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am not able to retrieve the `state` in the reducer

MyComponent looks like this

```
const MyComponent = ({name, features, onClick}) => {
  return (
        <div>
            Hello! {name}
            <Button onClick={() => { onClick(features); }}> Weight</Button>
        </div>
    );

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
  return {
    onClick: (features) => {
        dispatch(weightSort(features));
    }
  };
};
const mapStateToProps = (state: any, ownProps: any) => {
  console.log(state); //Displays the state
  return {
    name: "John Doe",
    features: ownProps.features,
  };
};

export const FeatureBlock = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

My actions and reducers looks like below:

```
// Action Creator
export const  weightSort = (features) => {
console.log("inside the weight sort action creator!!!");
  return {
    type: "SET_WEIGHT_FILTER",
    filter: "DESC",
    features,
  };
};

// Reducer
export const weightFilter = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_WEIGHT_FILTER":
        console.log(state); // Gives me empty state
        console.log("++inside weight filter+++++", action); //Displays action
        return state;
    default:
        return state;
  }
};


export const FeatureBlock = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(MyComponent);
```

What am I missing here? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your reducer, when you `console.log(state)`, it is correct in returning an empty array because you haven't done anything to modify it.

```
// Reducer
   export const weightFilter = (state = [1,2,3], action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
       case "SET_WEIGHT_FILTER":
           console.log(state); // This will show [1,2,3] because [1,2,3] is the initial state.
           console.log("++inside weight filter+++++", action); //Displays action
           return state;
       default:
           return state;
     }
   };
```

My guess is that you want something like this for your reducer:

```
// Action Creator
export const  weightSort = (name, features) => {
console.log("inside the weight sort action creator!!!");
  return {
    type: "SET_WEIGHT_FILTER",
    name,
    features,
  };
};
// Reducer
  export const weightFilter = (
    state = {
      name: '',
      features: [],
    },
    action
  ) => {
     switch (action.type) {
       case "SET_WEIGHT_FILTER":
           return {...state, name: action.name, features: action.features}
       default:
           return state;
     }
   };
```

and then in your `mapStateToProps` you would map out the attributes like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: any, ownProps: any) => {
  console.log(state); //Displays the state
  return {
    name: state.weightFilter.name,
    features: state.weightFilter.features,
  };
};
```

and your button would have a name prop passed into the function like so:

```
<Button onClick={() => { onClick(name, features); }}> Weight</Button>
```

If you would like to sort your data, you can do so either in the reducer or inside the container. I prefer to do it in the container and like to use the lodash `sortBy` function. It works like this:

```
import { sortBy } from 'lodash' //be sure to npm install lodash if you use this utility
...
...
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    name: state.weightFilter.name,
    features: sortBy(features, ['nameOfPropertyToSortBy'])
  };
}
```

Here is the lodash documentation on sortBy: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for the reply. If I had to sort the features based on a button click how would I do so?(I want to include the sorting in the component like you pointed out rightly) If I want to put it in mapDispatchToProps
    `function mapDispatchToProps = ({`
      `onFeaturesClick: orderFeatures`
    `})`
How would you do that?

Comment: You would create an action dispatch that takes in the name of an object's attribute so that you could pass that to your reducer. In your reducer, you can use the attribute passed from your action to sort the data in your reducer and return a new object. 

Another option would be to create a state property in the container where you render the data, like `sortProperty`, and bind an onClick handler to your buttons that setState on sortProperty. Then in the table that maps over the items, use a sorting function to order the items.